# Cron job not working for magnto 2

Tags: magento2.3, cron

My crons are not working on my magento2.3 site.
What can be the issue? I tried installing a new cron also, still, the same issue exists. I want to enable the cron for index management. The indexing is kept as **`Update on schedule`**". If I run `php bin/magento cron:run` command I am getting this error https://prnt.sc/olyag4

Comment: When you run this command does the cron schedules get created in cron_schedule table?

Comment: @Raj It gets created but i am getting this entry "indexer_reindex_all_invalid"

Comment: Please check for the job name cashback which has been created manually, it seems to be creating the error when running the command